# Transposing query results

Tags: sql, oracle

I have select statement that returns two values (one column, two rows). I'd like to change them so that I have two columns and one row. I know there is something like pivot but I'm not sure how to used that, as it requires aggregation values and I do not aggregate here anything. What would be the most performant way to accomplish this task? Thank you!

Comment: Can you please show us the query you have?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use `min()` and `max()`:

```
select min(col), max(col)
from (<your query here>) t;
```

Comment: I get error: 4 ORA-00904: "COL": invalid identifier SQL1.sql 71 22

Comment: @user1809566 . . . `col` is the name of the column in your query.  You don't specify what it is in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ROWNUM` pseudo-column to generate a unique identifier for each column and then you can use any aggregation function (as it will only be aggregating a single value):

```
SELECT value1, value2  /*, value3 ... */
FROM   ( SELECT your_column, ROWNUM AS rn FROM your_table_or_query )
PIVOT  ( MAX( your_column )
         FOR rn IN ( 1 AS value1, 2 As value2 /*, 3 AS value3 ... */ )
       );
```